# how do I reuse the dependencies defined in pom.xml in gradle

Tags: java, maven, gradle, dependencies, pom.xml

I want to reuse the dependencies defined in this [pom.xml file](http://maven.aliyun.com/nexus/content/repositories/central/org/activiti/activiti-ui-root/6.0.0/activiti-ui-root-6.0.0.pom) It's quite a long list of dependices. I want to reuse it for convenience.

so I added a line in my build.gradle file like this.:

```
dependencies {
   // unfortunately,  Gradle seems just ignore this line.
   compile("org.activiti:activiti-ui-root:6.0.0")  
}
```

But it seems that gradle just ingore this line.   What's the best way of reusing a pom file if I don't want to rewrite a long list of dependencies?

Please give me some advise, many thanks.

==============================

Thanks, all you guys.  finally I find "io.spring.gradle:dependency-management-plugin"  helps to solve my problem.

@madhead is right.  pom.xml just provide the version of jars,  but will not import any file into my project.

> That pom.xml does not actually define any dependencies, it only defines versions of artifacts in dependencyManagement block. Thus, depending on this artifact in Gradle does not bring any transitive dependencies in your project (neither it will in Maven, btw).

but it's OK.  the version information is enough.

This segment is what I  use to solve my problem.

```
buildscript {

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
    jcenter()     
}

dependencies {
    classpath "io.spring.gradle:dependency-management-plugin:1.0.3.RELEASE"
}  }
```

.......

project(':editor-image-generator') {

```
dependencyManagement {
  imports {
       // import the pom.xml from outside.
     mavenBom "org.activiti:activiti-ui-root:6.0.0"
  }
}

dependencies {
      // It's good to see that, you don't need to specify the version here.
      // with the mavenBom imported above,  you can always get the right version.
    compile("org.activiti:activiti-bpmn-model")
    testCompile("org.activiti:activiti-bpmn-converter")
    compile("org.activiti:activiti-image-generator")
    compile("org.imgscalr:imgscalr-lib:4.2")
    compile("org.slf4j:slf4j-api")
    testCompile("commons-io:commons-io")
    testCompile("junit:junit")
}
```

}

Comment: https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/artifact_dependencies_tutorial.html

Comment: I did not try but I think you can implement it. Inside Gradle setting file, you can implement function to read xml pom file, get all dependencies and then load them as Gradle dependencies. This is just an idea.

Comment: Why do you think Gradle ignores the line? How does the rest of your `build.gradle` look like?

Comment: You can migrate `pom` into `build.gradle` and just fix the things that potentially could not work. Just run `gradle init` inside the project with the `pom.xml`, as well I agree with Lu why you think Gradle does ignore this dependency?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That `pom.xml` does not actually define any dependencies, it only defines versions of artifacts in [`dependencyManagement` block](https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-dependency-mechanism.html#Dependency_Management). Thus, depending on this artifact in Gradle does not bring any transitive dependencies in your project (neither it will in Maven, btw).

What you can try in [Spring's dependency management plugin](https://github.com/spring-gradle-plugins/dependency-management-plugin) for Gradle. It allows to reuse that `dependencyManagement` block definition for BOMs in Gradle.

Comment: Thanks, @madhead,   you're right.   your information helps a lot.    Spring's dependency management plugin  is pretty useful,  and helps to solve the version problem.